# Each time I use a dplyr function, i get an error that colonnade() was deprecated in pillar 1.9.0

Tags: r, package

I work in R a lot and since a few months I get the following error after doing something with tidy:

```
Error:
! `colonnade()` was deprecated in pillar 1.9.0 and is now defunct.
i Please use `tbl_format_setup()` instead.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I can fix the issue by calling as.data.frame(df), after which it works again, but it is quite annoying. It is probably a dependency issue, but im always scared to mess around with my libraries...

Tried to update the packages, but the problem persists.

Does anyone know how I can fix it, such that my codes still work afterwards? :)

Sessioninfo:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plm_2.2-4         urca_1.3-0        tseries_0.10-48   aTSA_3.1.2        stargazer_5.2.2   data.table_1.13.0 lubridate_1.7.9   readxl_1.3.1      forcats_0.5.0    
[10] stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.2       purrr_0.3.4       readr_2.1.4       tidyr_1.1.2       tibble_3.0.3      ggplot2_3.4.4     tidyverse_1.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2        jsonlite_1.8.4    modelr_0.1.8      Formula_1.2-3     Rdpack_1.0.0      assertthat_0.2.1  TTR_0.24.2        blob_1.2.1        cellranger_1.1.0 
[10] pillar_1.9.0      backports_1.1.9   lattice_0.20-41   glue_1.4.2        quadprog_1.5-8    digest_0.6.25     rvest_0.3.6       colorspace_1.4-1  sandwich_2.5-1   
[19] pkgconfig_2.0.3   bibtex_0.4.2.3    broom_0.8.0       haven_2.3.1       scales_1.2.1      stringdist_0.9.8  tzdb_0.3.0        generics_0.1.3    farver_2.0.3     
[28] ellipsis_0.3.2    withr_2.5.2       maxLik_1.4-4      cli_3.6.1         quantmod_0.4.18   vars_1.5-6        strucchange_1.5-2 magrittr_1.5      crayon_1.3.4     
[37] fs_1.5.0          fansi_0.4.1       nlme_3.1-148      MASS_7.3-51.6     xts_0.12.1        xml2_1.3.2        tools_4.0.2       hms_0.5.3         gbRd_0.4-11      
[46] lifecycle_1.0.3   munsell_0.5.0     reprex_0.3.0      compiler_4.0.2    rlang_1.1.1       grid_4.0.2        miscTools_0.6-26  rstudioapi_0.11   labeling_0.3     
[55] gtable_0.3.0      DBI_1.1.0         curl_4.3          R6_2.5.0          zoo_1.8-8         bdsmatrix_1.3-4   utf8_1.1.4        stringi_1.4.6     matrixcalc_1.0-5 
[64] parallel_4.0.2    Rcpp_1.0.5        vctrs_0.6.2       dbplyr_1.4.4      tidyselect_1.1.0  lmtest_0.9-38
```

rlang::last_trace()

```
> rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)
<error/lifecycle_error_deprecated>
Error:
! `colonnade()` was deprecated in pillar 1.9.0 and is now defunct.
i Please use `tbl_format_setup()` instead.
---
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. \-tibble:::print.tbl(x)
  3.   +-cli::cat_line(format(x, ..., n = n, width = width, n_extra = n_extra))
  4.   | \-base::paste0(..., collapse = "\n")
  5.   +-base::format(x, ..., n = n, width = width, n_extra = n_extra)
  6.   \-tibble:::format.tbl(x, ..., n = n, width = width, n_extra = n_extra)
  7.     \-tibble::trunc_mat(x, n = n, width = width, n_extra = n_extra)
  8.       \-tibble:::shrink_mat(df, rows, n, star = has_rownames(x))
  9.         \-pillar::colonnade(df, has_row_id = if (star) "*" else TRUE)
 10.           \-lifecycle::deprecate_stop("1.9.0", "pillar::colonnade()", "pillar::tbl_format_setup()")
 11.             \-lifecycle:::deprecate_stop0(msg)
 12.               \-rlang::cnd_signal(...)
```

Comment: Which package did you try to upgrade? Try to upgrade `tibble` (which is the most likely package that relies on pillar) with `update.packages("tibble")`.

Comment: Show the output of your `sessionInfo()` so we can see the version numbers for all your loaded packages.

Comment: @MrFlick Added sessionInfo() to the post.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of packages to check. Did you run `rlang::last_trace()` like the error message suggested? You would need to run that right after you get the error. What was that output as well?

Comment: haha, I work as a researcher, so that might be the reason :')

I added the rlang::last_trace() to the post! 

The error immediately pops up after for instance the following code: 

u_root_test_tv <- u_root_test %>%
  group_by(brand) %>%
  filter(sum(ln.tv) != 0) %>%
  ungroup()

ps. thanks for properly formatting my post @MrFlick

Comment: So the traceback makes it look like the error is coming from `tibble:::print.tbl`. Your session info shows you are running `tibble_3.0.3` but the latest version on CRAN is tibble_3.2.1`. What happens when you run `install.packages("tibble")` exactly? That should update tibble to the latest version. You are also running kind of an old version of R (4.0.2). Actually I would first recommend updating your R version. That will require reinstalling packages but that should bring everything up to date.

Comment: Dear MrFlick. Thanks a lot for your help! I updated R, and after some confusing updating of tidyverse, the error is resolved (tibble is now version 3.2.1, which I think you identified correctly as the culprit...)  

I am confused regarding your statement that i had to reinstall packages. All of my old packages still seemed to be installed? 

Anyway, really appreciated your input and help!